# Ajax's Form to create new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register","Account",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod="POST",
    UpdateTargetId="Done",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess="SucceedCreatedNewAcc"
}
)) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()
//Fill in the form
 <div id="Done"></div>
}
```

My `register` method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

                return PartialView(model);
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }            
        return PartialView();
    }
```

My JS piece of `SucceedCreatedNewAcc`

```
function SucceedCreatedNewAcc()
{
    $( "#Done" ).html( "A new account has been created" );
}
```

I have 2 little issues

1. I don't know what I insert in the `SucceedCreatedNewAcc` to reset all form field I once filled in above. I would like to empty all of them.
2. How can I retrieve the successfully created account's username so that I can insert it into `SucceedCreatedNewAcc` to make my `html` text more meaningful i.e  `$( "#Done" ).html( "A new account @username has been created" );`

Comment: Use P-R-G pattern instead.  It's cleaner and a better practice

Comment: Oh thank you but why is that ?

Comment: Prevents the dreaded double post if the user refreshes

Comment: You're returning the view and inserting it into the div with id of `Done`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Nick Thank you, how can I fix it now ? I changed View into PartialView as above.

Comment: Remove `    UpdateTargetId="Done",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,` and in your controller post method return a value of whether the data is valid and then in your success javascript function do something based on the result such as redirect. Honestly with a register form I would not do an ajax form, I would just do a regular form post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use something like `document.getElementById('registerForm').reset()` or `$(’#registerForm’)[0].reset();` or
   `$(':input',’#registerForm’).not(':button,:submit,:reset,:hidden')
   .val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected')`
2. You use `AjaxOptions` with `UpdateTargetId="Done"` and `InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace`. That mean that html of element with id `Done` will be replaced with html that returns `Register` action of `Account` controller.
   So all that you need is return string like *"A new account @username has been created"* from controller action and remove `$( "#Done" ).html( "A new account has been created" );` from `SucceedCreatedNewAcc` function.